# Stopping Effect.ScrollTo() while it's scrolling?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Yeah, basically I have this:

```
Effect.ScrollTo("bottom", { duration: 5.0 });
```

So what I want is to stop this effect while it's scrolling whenever I want to.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var scrollEffect = Effect.ScrollTo("bottom", { duration: 5.0 });

...

scrollEffect.cancel();
```

This code below works perfectly for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body { font-size: 30px; }
        #destination { margin-top: 1400px; }
        #start { position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 20px;}
        #stop { position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 20px;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function startEffect() {
            scrollEffect = Effect.ScrollTo("destination", { duration: 8.0 }); return false;
        }

        function stopEffect() {
            scrollEffect.cancel(); return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="start" href="#" onclick="return startEffect();">Start Effect</a>
    <a id="stop" href="#" onclick="return stopEffect();">Stop Effect</a>
    <p id="destination">Scroll Destination</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Tyson - Well, it seems to work, but not the way I wanted. Your solution makes me go back to where the scroll started, and what I want is to have the scroll stop where it is. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: According to the docs, it should "stop the effect as is". http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/core-effects

Comment: Hmm, strange. Are you using Firefox 3?

Comment: Well, it works by itself, but not when integrated into my JavaScript. I could swear it is almost the same as your script, except it doesn't have return false, and it also has other code.

Comment: Well, you can see the working code below... at least, an excerpt :P

Answer (score 0):

What I currently have working currently is having a div as follows:

```
<div id="pausepos" style="position:absolute;"></div>
```

Then having the JavaScript cancel the scrolling and move it back to where the original position was:

```
    fallingPosTempArr = $("thetop").viewportOffset();
    fallingPosTemp = -1*fallingPosTempArr[1];

    $("pausepos").setStyle({
        "top" : fallingPosTemp + 'px'
    });

    scrollEffect.cancel();

    setTimeout(function () { Effect.ScrollTo("pausepos", { duration: 0.0 }); }, 10);
```

It works, but on slower browsers you can see how the page jumps back to the top and then back again.